# IntelliJ plugin template doesn't know about PsiJavaFile

Tags: intellij-plugin

I have an IntelliJ plugin, which was created from the github-template, that cannot resolve the class com.intellij.psi.PsiJavaFile.

Has anyone else run into this and figured out what needs to be configured?

I'm new to IntelliJ plugin development.  I followed the instructions detailed at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/github-template.html to create a plugin.

I imported the generated plugin into IntelliJ and everything seems OK.  No compile warnings, etc..., but when I try to use the class com.intellij.psi.PsiJavaFile, IntelliJ says it cannot resolve the class.

I imagine I'm missing a configuration somewhere that tells IntelliJ which libraries to import, but I'm not finding it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the dependency on the Java intellij plugin, which is not enabled by default as you won't need it for every custom plugin.

Add `com.intellij.java` to the `platformPlugins` section of the `gradle.properties` file:

```bash
# Plugin Dependencies -> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-dependencies.html
# Example: platformPlugins = com.intellij.java, com.jetbrains.php:203.4449.22
platformPlugins = com.intellij.java
```

---

To address that the IDE cannot resolve `PsiJavaClass` specifically, I don't think it exists. Are you looking for [PsiJavaFile](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiJavaFile.java) or [PsiClass](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiJavaFile.java)?

Comment: That was indeed the problem.  Thank you for responding.  As you noticed, I typo'd my question and the class name is actually com.intellij.psi.PsiJavaFile.  I'm not sure how you knew what needed to be updated, but I'm glad you did.  I didn't see anything in the IntelliJ documentation, but then again, I haven't used Gradle before so I could've just missed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those like me attempting to create a new plugin that works with Java PSI Files (I'm on Intellij Idea v. 2023.3.x Community Edition), the `PsiJavaFile` wasn't found until I added `"com.intellij.java"` to the build.gradle.kts in the intelliJ block and for the list of dependencies.

```
// Configure Gradle IntelliJ Plugin
// Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html
intellij {
    version.set("2023.1.5")
    type.set("IC") // Target IDE Platform

    plugins.set(listOf("com.intellij.java"))
}
```

Since the other answer worked for the OP but not for me, I searched around for java plugin within the IntelliJ documentation and found the com.intellij.java plugin ID listed in a list of plugins, so I followed the instructions I found on that page to get it added to my plugin's gradle:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-dependencies.html